# how to use alamofire httpstatusCode

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I want a diffrerent responseDecodable on the httpStatusCode

server return

```
if statusCode == 200
resonseBody
{id: number}

if statusCode 400..<500
resonseBody
{
code: String
timestamp: String
message: String
}
```

so now my code is

```
 AF.request(url, method: .post, headers: header).responseData { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data) :
                guard let response = response.response else {return}
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                switch response.statusCode {
                    case 200:
                    if let json = json as? [String: Any] , let message = json["id"] as? Int{print(message)}
                case (400..<500):
                    if let json = json as? [String: Any] , let message = json["message"] as? String{print(message)}
                default:
                    return
                }
            case .failure(let err) :
                print(err)
            }
        }
```

I try this code convert responseDecodable

```
struct a: Codable {var id: Int}

struct b: Codable{
    var code: String
    var timestamp: String
    var message: String
}

AF.request(url, method: .post, headers: header).responseDecodable(of: a.self) { response in
            guard let data = response.value else {return}
            print(data)
            }
            .responseDecodable(of: b.self) { response in
            guard let data = response.value else {return}
            print(data)
            }
```

but this way Regardless statusCode return both a and b

I want
stautsCode == 200 return a or
statusCode 400..<500 return b

What should I Do?

Comment: Rather than decoding JSON depending on the status code I recommend to decode into an enum with associated values with `success` and `failure` cases

Comment: Why don't you keep using `.responseData()`, and instead of calling `JSONSerialization`, you call `try JSONDecoder().decode(a.self)` or `b.self` depending on the `switch response.statusCode`?

Comment: because JSONDecoder will be removed in almofire6

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Alamofire does not have a “decode one object for success and another for failure” implementation. You'll have to do this yourself.

If you really want a one distinct object for 2xx responses and another for  4xx responses, there are a few approaches:

1. Use `validate` to handle the 2xx responses, and manually decode 4xx responses in the error handler.

   ```swift
   AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: header)
       .validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)             // only 2xx are auto-decoded for us; handle 4xx responses in `failure` handler
       .responseDecodable(of: Foo.self) { response in
           switch response.result {
           case .failure(let error):
               guard
                   let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode,
                   400 ..< 500 ~= statusCode,
                   let data = response.data,
                   let apiError = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ApiErrorResponse.self, from: data)
               else {
                   print("other error:", error)      // didn't parse `ApiErrorResponse` object, so obviously some other error
                   return
               }

               print("apiError:", apiError)          // this is our parsed API error object

           case .success(let foo):
               print("success:", foo)
           }
       }
   ```
2. If you want, you could write your own `ResponseSerializer` to parse 2xx and 4xx responses differently:

   ```swift
   struct ApiErrorResponse: Decodable, Error {
       let code: String
       let timestamp: String
       let message: String
   }

   final class ApiResponseSerializer<T: Decodable>: ResponseSerializer {
       lazy var decoder = JSONDecoder()

       private lazy var successSerializer = DecodableResponseSerializer<T>(decoder: decoder)
       private lazy var errorSerializer = DecodableResponseSerializer<ApiErrorResponse>(decoder: decoder)

       public func serialize(request: URLRequest?, response: HTTPURLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) throws -> T {
           if let error = error { throw error }

           guard let response = response else { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }

           switch response.statusCode {
               case 400 ..< 500:
               let apiErrorObject = try errorSerializer.serialize(request: request, response: response, data: data, error: nil)
               throw apiErrorObject

           default:
               return try successSerializer.serialize(request: request, response: response, data: data, error: nil)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And then you can do:

   ```swift
   AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: header)
       .response(responseSerializer: ApiResponseSerializer<Foo>()) { response in
           switch response.result {
           case .failure(.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .customSerializationFailed(error: let apiErrorObject))):
               print("api response error:", apiErrorObject)

           case .failure(let error):
               print("some other error:", error)

           case .success(let foo):
               print("success:", foo)
           }
       }
   ```

   I find the nesting of the parsed error object to be a little tedious, but it does abstract the 2xx vs 4xx logic out of the `response`/`responseDecoder` completion handler.

In both of these, I'm considering all 2xx responses as success, not just 200. Some servers return 2xx codes other than just 200.